# Problem compiling Arabic

Tags: unicode, arabic, utf8

When I write this code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage{arabtex}
\usepackage{utf8}
\setcode{utf8}
\begin{document}
Here is the word ``Arabic'' written in Arabic:  \<اَلْعَرَبِيَّةُ>. 
like this: \RL{عربي}.
\end{document}
```

The output is:

> Here is the word “Arabic” written in Arabic: ???????????????. like this: ????.

**I don't know why the Arabic letter don't appear?**

Comment: I get [this output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sKW6l.png) from your document in texlive, which I think is correct, although I can not read it.  These days it is probably better to use lualatex or xelatex and standard Arabic fonts rather than arabtex and pdflatex, but it should work. Check your file is in UTF-8.

Comment: for the output is correct but i don't understand your suggestion well.

Comment: do as I did copy the document from this websi (not your original file) just as you posted above to a new document in an empty folder and try  with pdftex, you should get the output that I showed.

Comment: I have visible Arabic texts if I compile your example in `lualatex` and change the default font to Times. The document just needs a package `fontspec` and `\setmainfont{Times}`.

Answer (score 1):

There should be no need to use packages like `arabtex` etc. anymore.

I suggest you use `LuaLaTeX` together with `fontspec`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Tahoma}

\begin{document}

Hello, world!\par

\raggedleft
مرحبا بالعالم

\end{document}
```

See if that works. Make sure your editor saves the file in UTF-8 format, and to compile with LuaLaTeX (or XeLaTeX, if you want).